# Show a message box after usercontrol fully displayed

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, messagebox, paintevent

I have a `control form` derived from a *windows User Control class*. I need to show a `message box` based on a condition once the form displayed. I tried to use the `form paint event handler` to do this but it seems firing twice. As a result `message box` displayed twice. How can this be done?

```
public partial class SelectAccounts : UserControl
{
    private void SelectAccounts_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("something");
    }
}
```

Comment: show what you have tried ...

Comment: VisibleChanged/OnVisibleChanged?

Comment: @GregD I used Paint event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've deleted my previous answer you may try the below code.
Using variable to remember if the user control is loaded or not.

```
    public partial class SelectAccounts : UserControl
    {
        bool _Shown = false;
        private void SelectAccounts_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this._Shown)
            {
                this._Shown = true;
                MessageBox.Show("something");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then moved this._Shown = true; before MessageBox.Show("something");

Comment: public class MyUserControl : UserControl {
        public event EventHandler Shown;
        public bool IsShown { get; private set; }
        public MyUserControl () : base() { }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            if (!IsShown) {
                IsShown = true;          
                if (Shown.IsNotNull()) {
                    Shown(this, e);
                }
                OnShown(this, e);
            }
        }
        protected virtual void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
    }