# Do something after the usercontrol is loaded and displayed WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` and I am loading it dynamically in a `ContentControl` on a `Button` **click**. I have a `TextBlock` in the `UserControl` and I want to show some text dynamically (which is basically a status which my another method will return while processing a request) in the `TextBlock` after the `UserControl` is loaded. I tried setting up this in a `Loaded` **event** of the `UserControl` but the text is already there when the `UserControl` is fully loaded and showed.

Can someone please give an idea about how to achieve this. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303166/show-a-message-box-after-usercontrol-fully-displayed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708039/what-event-is-fired-when-a-usercontrol-is-displayed/4708172#4708172) link but none seems to be working for me.

Thanks Deepak

Answer (score 0):

If your loading is **logical** rather than **physical** you must handle it yourself.

Particularly you must have a way to tell the `UserControl` when the data are loaded.

Here is a full sample using **MVVM** (not perfect):

The `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.LoadDataView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVizConverter"></BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
        <local:ReverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="reverseBoolToVizConverter"></local:ReverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Model.IsLoadingData,Converter={StaticResource boolToVizConverter}}">...</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Model.IsLoadingData,Converter={StaticResource reverseBoolToVizConverter}}">Data loaded</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

So `"..."` is displayed while we are loading (in a real application you would use a better UI control to render this status like a `ProgressRing`).

And when the data are loaded we display `"Data loaded"`.

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class LoadDataView : UserControl
    {
        public LoadDataViewModel Model
        {
            get { return (LoadDataViewModel)GetValue(ModelProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ModelProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Model", typeof(LoadDataViewModel), typeof(LoadDataView));

        public LoadDataView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

The view model:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class LoadDataViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool isLoadingData = false;
        public bool IsLoadingData
        {
            get { return isLoadingData; }
            set
            {
                if (value != isLoadingData)
                {
                    isLoadingData = value;
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsLoadingData"));
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    }
}
```

Here is the main view:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl x:Name="content"></ContentControl>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Display data</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

When we click the Button we display the data `UserControl` and we trigger the loading:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadDataViewModel model = new LoadDataViewModel { IsLoadingData = true };

    content.Content = new LoadDataView { Model = model };

    await Task.Delay(3000);

    model.IsLoadingData = false;
}
```

The `async`/`await` and `Task` stuff is just there to simulate the loading of the data.

Finally here is the reverse bool to visibility converter:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ReverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```